# c# How to apply empty cell by using StringBuilder

Tags: c#, excel, whitespace, stringbuilder

I am filling excel cells with StringBuilder with codes below.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sr = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sr.Append("Value1" + "$");
sr.Append("$"); //I jump to next cell here with null value. 
sr.Append("Value2" +"$");

string[] array = sr.ToString().Replace("\r\n", string.Empty).Split('$');

for (int i = 0; i < dizi.Length; i++)
{
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range myRange = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xws.Cells[StartRow,StartCol + i];
myRange.Value2 = array[i];
}
```

I use "$" and split it for leaving empty cell and jump to next cell. But it creates whitespace. 
How can i jump to next cell without adding whitespace?

Comment: Show the code where you "jump to next cell" and explain how do you "fill excel cells with StringBuilder" please.

Comment: Sorry for late answer i edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple answer -- just run this check after you get myRange:

```
  if( !String.IsNullOrEmpty( array[i] ) )
  {
       myRange.Value2 = array[i];
  }
```

You just want to prevent setting the text if it's empty, right?  Simple.

Comment: This solved my problem. I did not expect it would be that simple. Thanks!